# Warning: "'myAge' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selected"

Tags: objective-c, methods, int, warnings

I've looked everywhere but still can't fix this warning.

interface:

```
-(void) myInfo: (int) myAge: (int) myHeight;
```

I know it's just a warning but I have no idea why it's happening. Any help is appreciated. THank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the warning, declare the function as follows:

```
- (void) myInfo:(int)myAge height:(int)myHeight;
```

This will give you a method that you can call with the following syntax (assuming the method is called from within the class declaring the method):

```
[self myInfo:10 height:100]
```

Take a look at the section "Methods Can Take Parameters" at the following URL: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW5 for a thorough explanation.

> #### For convenience her is the relevant section:
>
> If you need to supply multiple parameters, the syntax is again quite different from C. Multiple parameters to a C function are specified inside the parentheses, separated by commas; in Objective-C, the declaration for a method taking two parameters looks like this:

```
- (void)someMethodWithFirstValue:(SomeType)value1 secondValue:(AnotherType)value2;
```

> In this example, value1 and value2 are the names used in the implementation to access the values supplied when the method is called, as if they were variables.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can "fix" it like this in pch file for whole project

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-selector-name"
```